# How access python privet variable inside init function

Tags: python, oop

How to override **details()** method in child class **Doctor**
.I want to override the details method to return id, name and Regno
current code gives an error

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.__id = id
        self.__name = name

    def details(self):
        return self.__id, self.__name


class Doctor(Member):
    def __init__(self, id, name, drNumber):
        super().__init__(id, name)
        self.__drNumber = drNumber

    def details(self):
        return self.__id, self.__name, self.__regNo


doc = Doctor(1123, "Tim", "xxx5678")
print(doc.details())
```

Comment: `__name_mangling` is deliberately to _prevent_ accessing inherited attributes - if that's not the behaviour you want, _don't use it_.

Comment: Care to share the error details?

Comment: you assign `self.__drNumber = drNumber` then try to read it as `self.__regNo`.

Comment: `return super().details() + (self.__drNumber,)` avoids the need to reference the private attributes of the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the private attributes, because the name mangling adds the current class to the name, so it won't find the attribute with the parent's name.

Instead, call the parent method and add your value to the result.

```
class Doctor(Member):
    def __init__(self, id, name, drNumber):
        super().__init__(id, name)
        self.__drNumber = drNumber

    def details(self):
        parent_details = super().details()
        return parent_details + (self.__drNumber,)
```